# Xdocument.Load is failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmltextwriter, xmltextreader

I am unable to load Xdocument.Load  I am unable to load Xdocument.LoadI am unable to load Xdocument.LoadI am unable to load Xdocument.LoadI am unable to load Xdocument.LoadI am unable to load Xdocument.LoadI am unable to load Xdocument.LoadI am unable to load Xdocument.LoadI am unable to load Xdocument.Load

```
   public void AuthorNames(string Uri)
    {

        CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
        credentialCache.Add(
        new Uri("https://www.RESTWEBSERVICESSITE.com"),
        "Basic",
        new NetworkCredential("USERID", "PWD"));


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Uri);
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.Credentials = credentialCache;
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {

                XmlReader responseReader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream());

                //XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

                **XDocument docs = XDocument.Load();**

               // responseReader.Read();
                //XDocument docs = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());


          List<string> books = docs.Descendants("INTEL")
          // Not really necessary, but makes it simpler
        .Select(x => new {
           Title = (string) x.Element("TITLE"),
           Author = x.Element("INTEL_AUTH")
           })
      .Select(x => new {
           Title = x.Title,
           FirstName = (string) x.Author.Element("FNAME"),
           MiddleInitial = (string) x.Author.Element("MNAME"),
           LastName = (string) x.Author.Element("LNAME"),
        })
   .Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1} {2} {3}",
                           x.Title,
                           x.FirstName, x.MiddleInitial, x.LastName))
   .ToList();

   for (int i = 0; i < books.Count; i++)
   {
    for (int j = 0; j < books.Count; j++)
    {
    Response.Write("--" + books[i] + "---" + books[j]);
    }
   }
```

}

```
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Remote server Returned an Error.");
        }
    }
```

I am unable to load xdocument.Load with the XML feed.

Comment: Any reason for using `XmlTextReader` instead of (say) LINQ to XML? (You should also consider breaking out your big code into smaller methods, changing indentation styles, and using a StringBuilder instead of string concatenation.)

Comment: I didn't know how to use linq that is the reason I am using XMLTEXTReader. I will change it into string builder instead of concatenation.

Comment: I think what @JonSkeet is saying is, you may as well just rewrite the entire thing. :)

Comment: @SmilingLily: It would be *much* simpler using LINQ to XML. Heck, it would be simpler using `XmlDocument`, but LINQ to XML makes it a breeze.

Comment: Do you know what can I change to print author names associated with the tile?

Comment: I will look into changing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear *exactly* what you want, but I suspect it's something like this:

```
XDocument doc = ...; // However you want to load this.
// Note: XML is case-sensitive, which is one reason your code failed before
List<string> books = doc
    .Descendants("Intel")
    // Not really necessary, but makes it simpler
    .Select(x => new {
               Title = (string) x.Element("Title"),
               Author = x.Element("Intel_auth")
            })
    .Select(x => new {
               Title = x.Title,
               FirstName = (string) x.Author.Element("fname"),
               MiddleInitial = (string) x.Author.Element("mname"),
               LastName = (string) x.Author.Element("lname"),
            });
    .Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1} {2} {3}",
                               x.Title,
                               x.FirstName, x.MiddleInitial, x.LastName))
    .ToList();
```

This will give you a `List<string>` where each element is something like "Test 1: John M. pp".

Comment: I created a new xml document Because I didn't want to show the real data. I might have typed wrong but my code is well checked for case sensitivity. So that was not a problem. Thank you for the reply. I tried the code you listed above and I am getting some errors. Pasting code below so that you can see the red lines.

Comment: List<string> books = doc
    .Descendants("Intel")
     .Select(x => new {
               Title = (string) x.Element("Title"),
               Author = x.Element("Intel_auth")
            })
    .Select(x => new {
               Title = x.Title,
               FirstName = (string) x.Author.Element("fname"),
               MiddleInitial = (string) x.Author.Element("mname"),
               LastName = (string) x.Author.Element("lname"),
            });

Comment: .Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1} {2} {3}",
                               x.Title,
                               x.FirstName, x.MiddleInitial, x.LastName))
    .ToList();

Comment: @SmilingLily: Comments are just plain text. We can't see red lines. And it *really* helps if you make your actual data correspond with your real data... the values don't have to be the same, but it's not going to work if we can't see what the element names are...

Comment: I am having Issues When I try to Load the Xdocument.

Comment: //XDocument docs = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream()); This is coming Empty So when I tried    XmlReader responseReader = XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream());
                  
                   
                    XDocument docs = XDocument.Load(responseReader);  Still Docs is coming Empty  ResponseReader.read() is loading the document and When I try to     XDocument docs = XDocument.Load(responseReader.Read()); It is giving me error. How can I fix that??

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you added it works fine. Just that the xdocument doesn't load it is not returning anything. When I try to load xdocument.load(xmlreader.read()) The best overloadmethod match for xdocument.load has some Invalid Arguments.

Comment: @SmilingLily: So that's where you look at the documentation for `XDocument.Load` and see what it can take. There's no need for an `XmlReader` at all here - just use the response stream directly.

Comment: If I put the response directly xdocument.load(response);It is giving me the overloaded method has some invalid some arguments error.

Comment: @SmilingLily: The response *stream*: `response.GetResponseStream()`

Comment: XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream()) 'response.GetResponseStream()' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' System.Xml.Linq.XDocument

Comment: I added request.keepalive = live   XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream()) This expression causes side effects and will not be evaluated System.Xml.Linq.XDocument

Comment: @SmilingLily: Are you calling that after you've already used the response somewhere else (e.g. you've still got the XmlReader)?

Comment: @SmilingLily: It's not clear where you've tried to put that KeepAlive part... but you shouldn't just be guessing. Really try to understand what's going on. I suggest you edit your question to include the updated code - just as far as constructing the XDocument.

Comment: @SmilingLily: As I suggested, you're still creating an `XmlReader`. Why are you doing that?

Comment: I am not using it. I commented it out. I was just checking by uncommenting and see if works (Nope). Still I don't have any way to Load the XDocument with the xml feed.

Comment: Xdocument doc = Xdocument.Load(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()));  worked Great // I can see the data But the Lynq query is n't returning anything. I checked the tag names they are all right. In my <xml> Before the <intel> I have 2 <dmd:IndexEntry> tags ??

Comment: The Linq code you added is printing only one author name. SOme books are written by more than one author for that the tags are <INTEL><INTEL_AUTH><FNAME><FNAME>....etc</INTEL_AUTH><INTEL_AUTH><FNAME><FNAME>....etc</INTEL_AUTH><INTEL_AUTH><FNAME><FNAME>....etc</INTEL_AUTH></INTEL>

Comment: @SmilingLily: Then you'll need to handle that differently, using `Elements` instead of `Element`. Your question didn't give any indication about what you wanted to happen in that case. You've got to learn to be more precise with your questions.

Comment: I wanted to print Title of the book + all author names next to it. I modified the Author = x.elements("INTEL_AUTH") but I am getting errors in the firstname section.

Comment: .Select(x => new {
           Title = (string)x.Element(ns+"TITLE"),
               Author = x.Elements(ns+"INTELLCONT_AUTH"),


            })
    .Select(x => new {
               Title = x.Title,
               FirstName = (string) x.Author.Elements(ns+"FNAME"),
               MiddleInitial = (string) x.Author.Element(ns+"MNAME"),
               LastName = (string) x.Author.Element(ns+"LNAME"),
            })
    .Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1} {2} {3}",
                               x.Title,
                               x.FirstName, x.MiddleInitial, x.LastName))
    .ToList();

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < books.Count; i++)
{    
        Response.Write("--" + books[i] + "---" );
}  Error 26 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Element' and no extension method 'Element' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @SmilingLily: As I've said before, please don't post large sections of code in comments. It's not helpful - it's virtually impossible to read. It sounds like this should probably be in a new question - but *please* put effort into asking it as clearly as possible, having read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I already asked it as a new question. Please check the link below. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9704989/how-can-i-loop-through-all-the-elements-in-select-statement-in-linq#comment12335405_9704989