# How can I loop Through all the elements in .select statement in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to Print "Title of the Book , AuthorNames " (Some Books have more than one author)
Below Linq code is printing only first author. How can I print all the authors associated with a book?

```
 List<string> books = docs.Descendants(name)

   .Select(x => new {
       Title = (string)x.Element(ns+"TITLE"),
           Author = x.Element(ns+"INTEL_AUTH")
        })
.Select(x => new {
           Title = x.Title,
           FirstName = (string) x.Author.Element(ns+"FNAME"),
           MiddleInitial = (string) x.Author.Element(ns+"MNAME"),
           LastName = (string) x.Author.Element(ns+"LNAME"),
        })
.Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1} {2} {3}",
                           x.Title,
                           x.FirstName, x.MiddleInitial, x.LastName))
.ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < books.Count; i++)
{       
   Response.Write("--" + books[i] + "<BR />" );      
}
```

**XML**
Here is the xml code.
     
    
    
     TEST 1 
    
      JOHN
    
     DOE
    
    
    JOHN
     
     SKEET

```
 <INTEL_AUTH ID="10">
 <FNAME>JO</FNAME>
 <MNAME></MNAME>
 <LNAME>JO</LNAME>
 <INTEL_AUTH>
 </INTEL>

  <INTEL>
  <TILE> LEARNING LINQ</TITLE>
  <INTEL_AUTH ID="2">
  <FNAME> SHELLY</FNAME>
  <MNAME></MNAME>
  <LNAME>SHELLY</LNAME>
  <INTEL_AUTH iD="3">
  <FNAME>CHRIS</FNAME>
  <MNAME></MNAME>
  <LNAME>MADISON</LNAME>
  </INTEL_AUTH>


  </INTEL>
  </RECORD>
  </XML>
```

I WANT THE OUTPUT TO BE DISPLAYED LIKE : (TITLE) : ALL AUTHORS WHO WROTE THAT BOOK

TEST 1 : JOHN DOE , JOHN SKEET , JO JO
LEARNING LINQ : SHELLY SHELLY , CHRIS MADISON

Comment: Post part of xml, it'll be easier to help you

Comment: Check out SelectMany: http://jesseliberty.com/2011/03/22/linq-selectmany/

Comment: "How can I print all the authors associated with a book?" - by _not_ destroying all structure with string.Format().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want a single result with multiple authors, or a single result per author, or how you'd expect this to be represented in a `List<string>`. I suspect this will do what you need though:

```
var query = docs.Descendants(name)
    // First get the relevant elements out of the main book element
    .Select(x => new {
        Title = (string) x.Element(ns + "TITLE"),
        Authors = x.Elements(ns + "INTEL_AUTH")
     })
    // Now transform them from LINQ to XML into plain objects
    .Select(x => new {
        Title = x.Title,
        Authors = x.Authors.Select(a => new {
            FirstName = (string) a.Element(ns + "FNAME"),
            MiddleInitial = (string) a.Element(ns + "MNAME"),
            LastName = (string) a.Element(ns + "LNAME")
        })
     });

 foreach (var book in query)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("{0}:", book.Title);
     foreach (var author in book.Authors)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("  {0} {1} {2}",
                           author.FirstName, author.MiddleInitial,
                           author.LastName);
     }
 }
```

Comment: You replaced the books with Query so Books doesn't exist in the current context (Getting an error in the for each loop) All the below 3 code lines are giving errors  FirstName = (string) a.Author.Element(ns + "FNAME"),
            MiddleInitial = (string) a.Author.Element(ns + "MNAME"),
            LastName = (string) a.Author.Element(ns + "LNAME")

Comment: Error 25 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a definition for 'Author' and no extension method 'Author' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @SmilingLily: Fixed both, but to be honest you need to be able to *understand* the code well enough to fix typos for yourself. If you can't understand what the code is doing, you'll never be able to maintain it without a constant stream of questions to SO.

Comment: If A book name is : Learning Linq and if it's written by Jon Skeet , JoJo , John Doe I would like it to be displayed as     Learning LINQ : Jon skeet , JoJo, John Doe.

Comment: @SmilingLily: Well I'm afraid you'll have to work out how to do that part for yourself - I *did* suggest that you read up on how to ask a good question, and instead you posted a question without really saying what you wanted. Your question asked: "How can I print all the authors associated with a book?" - and my answer does that. I'm afraid I'm too busy to keep going back and forth forever on this.

Comment: foreach (var author in book.Authors)  book.authors is coming empty. so the above code is printing only titles.I just am writing it here so that I won't be confused .

Comment: Ok It printed. I did a typo for Authors tag.

Answer (score 1):

I select all authors into an IEnumerable then Aggregate them:

```
var books = docs.Descendants(name)    
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Title = (string)x.Element(ns + "TITLE"),
                    Author = x.Elements(ns + "INTEL_AUTH") // Elements not Element here
                })
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    Title = x.Title,
                    Names = x.Author.Select(i => new
                    {
                        FirstName = (string)i.Element(ns + "FNAME"),
                        MiddleInitial = (string)i.Element(ns + "MNAME"),
                        LastName = (string)i.Element(ns + "LNAME")
                    })
                })
                .Select(x => string.Format("{0}: {1}",
                                   x.Title,
                                   x.Names
                                        .Select(i => 
                                            string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", 
                                                i.FirstName, 
                                                i.MiddleInitial, 
                                                i.LastName))
                                       .Aggregate((working, next) => 
                                           working + " | " + next)))
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Above code is not returning any elements. Books.Count is null

Comment: Something must have changed then